# Populate UserForm Combobox with values from non continous range through RowSource property

Tags: excel, combobox, vba

I have a range containing cells whose contents I want to use to populate a Userform ComboBox through the RowSource property. 
However, I don't seem to get it to work. I've tried various different approaches, but nothing seems to work!

Here is a wild array of ways I've tried:

```
cb_FcnName.RowSource = Worksheets(3).Name & "!" & NameRng.Address
cb_FcnName.RowSource = Worksheets(3).Name & "!" & NameRng.Value
cb_FcnName.RowSource = Worksheets(3).Name & "!" & Range(NameRng)
cb_FcnName.RowSource = Worksheets(3).Name & "!" & Range("NameRng")
cb_FcnName.RowSource = Worksheets(3).Name & "!" & Range("NameRng").Address
cb_FcnName.RowSource = "'" & Worksheets(3).Name & "'!" & NameRng.Address
cb_FcnName.RowSource = Worksheets("Features") & "!" & NameRng.Value
cb_FcnName.RowSource = "'" & Worksheets("Features") & "!'" & "B2.Value"
```

Does anybody have an idea how to geht the values from the cells into my ComboBox? Even a pointer in the right direction is much appreciated!

Many thanks in advance!

**Edit:** Not sure if this is part of the problem, but the Range is not continuous!

Comment: `ComboBox` doesn't have `RowSource` property

Comment: What does doesn't work mean? Are you getting error messages? And is this a userform combobox?

Comment: I think the problem may be that your NameRng is not contiguous. Can you try with a contiguous range such as A1:A10?

Comment: @QHarr : Yes, it's a Userform Combobox. I've added the info above! Thanks.

Comment: @SJR : Added the info about discontinuity, thanks!

Comment: Yes I think RowSource won't work with a non-contiguous range so you could use AddItem and loop through each cell adding individually, which is slow but should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is rather cumbersome but I think it will work. It puts the values in column AQ so just change to somewhere you don't use or put on a hidden sheet. The alternative as I said above is to use AddItem.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim r As Range, r1 As Range

With Worksheets(2)
    Set r = Union(.Range("A1:A10"), .Range("B1:B3"))
    For Each r1 In r.Areas
        r1.Copy .Range("AQ" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2)
    Next r1
    Me.ComboBox1.RowSource = .Name & "!" & .Range("AQ2").CurrentRegion.Address
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change this:

```
cb_FcnName.RowSource = Worksheets("Features") & "!" & NameRng.Value
```

To something like this:

```
cb_FcnName.List = Worksheets("Features").Range("NameRng").Value
```

Or this will also do:

```
cb_FcnName.RowSource = "NameRng"
```

Comment: I've tried your first solution and I get a "Runtime Error 1004: Application or objectdefined error".

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cb_FcnName.RowSource = Range("NameRng").Worksheet.Name & "!" & Range("NameRng").Address
```

It can be further simplified but the above assumes you have a named range, however it doesn't guess what worksheet it is in.

Comment: I've tried your solution, and it throws a "Runtime Error 1004: Method Range failed for object "_Global".